# Why are the stems left on when cooking an artichoke?

Tags: artichokes

In several YouTube videos on preparing artichokes the cooks recommend leaving the stem on the artichoke while it is boiling.

Why is this?

Comment: In my family, the stem was trimmed (a couple of mm), peeled, cut off (so that the artichoke would be able to stand upright in the pan), then thrown in the pan with the rest of the artichoke.  As mentioned below, the peeled stem, once cooked is similar in texture to the heart, and delicious.

Answer (score 7):

The stem is an extension of the heart, and is good to eat. The stem may be peeled prior to cooking to remove tough exterior, this applies more to older artichokes that are more open. Young artichokes that are still tightly closed don’t generally have tough stems.

Comment: The stems are usually good, sometimes they can be a bit tough, the only way to know for sure is to cook them and see. It's always a good idea to trim a half inch off the bottom of the stem before you do.